# PHP Mysqli Class Extends

Tags: php, mysqli, extends

**Problem resolved. UserControl function closing db connection. Thanks**

When I tired the `real_escape_string()` function, there is a problem

> Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in ...

SqlClass:

```
class Sql {

    protected $mysqli = '';
    private $table = '';
    private $where = '';
    private $limit = '';
    private $orderby = '';
    private $data = '';
    private $columns = '';

    function __construct(){
        try{
            if(!$this->mysqli){
                $this->mysqli = new mysqli(VTConnectIP, VTConnectRoot, VTConnectPass, VTConnectDB)
                                                                        or die(mysqli_connect_error());
                $this->tr_fix_db();
            }
            return;
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage(); 
        }   
    }
```

Extends Class:

```
class LoginClass extends Sql
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $errors = array();

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function username($data){
        $this->UserControl($data);
        $this->username = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($data); // Error Code
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: `$this->mysqli` does not contain what you expect it to. Debug it. `var_dump($this->mysqli)`

Comment: i checked before this line $this->username = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($data); // Error Code and bool(true)

Comment: If `$this->mysqli` is `bool(true)` then at some point you have overwritten it prior to the `username()` call.  It shouldn't be a bool, it should be an `object mysqli {...}`

Comment: i used var_dump after mysqli(VTConnectIP, VTConnectRoot, VTConnectPass, VTConnectDB), and object(mysqli)#2 (19) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { }

Comment: out of my mind, just like that... when you put `or die(mysqli_connect_error())`. Could it make the statement to return as a boolean? Thus the mysqli object being a `bool(true)` in the other var_dump

Comment: @Actionsee That's fine, but you also need to check it just before you use it in `username()` because it has been modified.  Search your code for `$this->mysqli =` to see where you are reassigning it.

Comment: pfff i used db close event. `function db_close(){
   $this->mysqli = $this->mysqli->close();
   return $this;
  }` and when i delete `$this->mysqli = $this->mysqli->close();` its ok :S Thanks :) and i used UserControl function. It's closing db connection. Before real_escape_string